# PlayStore Screenshot Resolution / Aspect Ratios for Tablets

Tags: android, google-play

since I recently was tasked to create pictures for an app for the PlayStore, I kind of stumbled when it came to making ones for tablets.

Most phones feature a 16:9 aspect ratio from what I know, and most will be around FHD I suppose.

Tablets on the other hand surely do have a different aspect ratio and resolution. What are the most common ones? Are there certain resolutions suggested by Google which one should cover?

I was only linked to the following help article, and it was not all that helpful regarding this topic: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en-GB

Is there some guide someone can recommend when it comes to this? I know for example there is a rather thorough article when it comes to [screenshots on the AppStore](https://www.appshots.io/app-screenshot-guide). Does anyone know of something equivalent regarding the PlayStore and Android?

Comment: from the link that you have posted, I think the following is applicable for both phones as well as tablets.

To publish your Store Listing, you must provide a minimum of 2 screenshots.
JPEG or 24-bit PNG (no alpha)
Minimum dimension: 320 px
Maximum dimension: 3840 px

Comment: @VivekMishra yes. But are there any resolutions one would recommend? For example posting 2 320px pictures would be totally fine by this guide, however I doubt anyone would recommend only using such (by today’s standards) low resolution ones

Comment: @VivekMishra furthermore: would it make sense to only use 16:9 aspect ratio pictures? I don’t think either because surely not every device has that aspect ratio. So I had hoped someone could point me in a direction as to what the most common resolutions and aspect ratios are, that I should tackle

Comment: most probably aspect ratio will be maintained if you capture screenshot from the tablets.

Comment: @VivekMishra the pictures being posted will be not screenshots per se but ones embedded in device mockups and maybe supplemented by text. So the aspect ratio itself will not be independent from the screenshot itself. (I hope that made sense :D )

Comment: well this may not appropriate way but you can capture a screenshot in your tablet and then check the resolution of the captured image in your phone's gallery

Comment: @VivekMishra thanks for the suggestion, but I think not everybody will have the same device as me. That’s why I wanted to make 2 - 3 different “sets” of pictures but I don’t know what resolutions to tackle ;)

Comment: different sets are not required by the way for screenshots on play store. You can add for 7 and 10 inches and that will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to this problem:

- Go to Geizhals.de (not getting paid, read on to see why I use them)
- Go to the tablet section
- Filter for 7 inch (min size & max size to 7 inch)
- Click advanced filters
- See the different aspect ratios and how many search results there are

As of 12th Sept 2020, these seem to be the most popular by far:

- [7 inch](https://geizhals.de/?cat=nbtabl&xf=2388_7.9%7E2389_7): 15/9
- [10 inch](https://geizhals.de/?cat=nbtabl&xf=2388_10.9%7E2389_10): 16/10